# FFmpeg: Adding a new audio into video and adjust volume of both audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to add a new audio file to the existing audio track in my video.

**1.** If the video is longer, I want the newly added audio to repeat throughout the entire video, but if the video is shorter than the audio, the audio can be cut short. In any case, I would prefer the video to end at its original duration.

**2.** I want to be able to adjust the volume levels of both the audio from the original video and the newly added audio.

Currently I know this command but it only replaces the voice.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest output.mp4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `... -map 0 -map 1 -filter:a:0 "volume=1.2" -filter:a:1 "volume=1.3" ...`

Comment: Thanks for the code! Well how can we combine the a0 and a1 filters so that the existing audio and the newly added audio play at the same time?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i audio.mp3 -lavfi "[0:a]volume=1.2[a];[1]volume=1.3[b];[a][b]amix=2:shortest" -c:v copy -c:a aac -q:a 4 out.mp4` not tested